# Animate Body scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website i will have a right and left panel. Right panel contains all the links and Left panel contains all the videos.When user clicked on a link i have to animate the body scroll with smooth animation and need to highlight the particular video background by applying new class name and while scrolling need to remove the class name(new class name).Here my issue is some delay while applying animation effect while adding the new class name.can anyone help us to resovle this issue. 
Here im attaching the code.Please check.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('.sub-cat-list a[href*="#"]').click(function (e){    
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickURL = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
        var target = this.hash; 
        var offTop =  parseInt(jQuery(target).offset().top);
        var scroLtoP = parseInt(jQuery(window).scrollTop());

        if (typeof(jQuery(target).offset()) != 'undefined') { 
            jQuery( "html, body" ).animate({
                scrollTop: offTop 
             },800).promise().done(function(even) { 
                jQuery(target).parent().addClass('focusin');
                setTimeout(function(){                      
                    removeFocClass(target); 
                },900);
            });         
        }
    });

function removeFocClass(curEle)
{
    var menuTargetFC = jQuery(curEle).parent().hasClass('focusin');     
    if(menuTargetFC)
    {       
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){           
            jQuery(curEle).parent().removeClass('focusin');         
        });     
    }   
    else{
        jQuery(curEle).parent().addClass('focusin');        
    }       
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change this:

```
jQuery( "html, body" ).animate({
            scrollTop: offTop 
         },800).promise().done(function(even) { 
            jQuery(target).parent().addClass('focusin');
            setTimeout(function(){                      
                removeFocClass(target); 
            },900);
        });
```

to this:

```
jQuery(target).parent().addClass('focusin');
jQuery( "html, body" ).animate({
            scrollTop: offTop 
         },800).promise().done(function(even) { 
            setTimeout(function(){                      
                removeFocClass(target); 
            },900);
        });
```

so you will add class before animating and will avoid 800ms animation delay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have already tried that. But First time, when the user clicked on a link its worked and then if they clicked same link more than one time again im facing same some delay on animating effect while adding the class name(new class name).

Comment: Could you send me the jsfiddle or plunker with all the code, or at least with both html / js so I could take a look at that?